# Difference between electrical conductivity and optical conductivity

Tags: condensed-matter, material-science, semiconductor-physics, spectroscopy, nanoscience

Is there any difference between electrical conductivity and optical conductivity? How to explain it physically and is there any method available to connect them mathematically?
If I  calculate carrier concentration of a thin-film material by optical means ( say Swanepoel and Wemple-Didominico method) and electrical method ( say Hall measurement Van der Pauw method). Is there any difference between them and if yes how to connect them with a mathematical relation and how to explain it physically. Thank you.

Comment: What does "optical conductivity" mean to you?  I can think of different meanings.

Comment: if you mean fiber optics they are generally not electrical conductors

Comment: By optical conductivity, I mean conductivity that arises due to optical excitation without an external electric field. I am considering here a Transparent Conducting  Oxide material thin film which is transparent as well as conductive.

Comment: So you're referring to electrical conductivity that happens when light produces charge carriers?

Comment: Yes, conductivity subject to an optical excitation without external electric field.